# Identifying sequences per column

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, rle

I am working with time-use data and want to calculate the duration of a started measurement at each time step (per column) and select the longest duration for each measurement. The measurement are numbered from `1` to `27`. The length is weighted with `1 (e.g increment is set to 1).`  I am not sure how to handle if a measurement is fragmented and has multiple durations times.

Data format:

[image]

Desired output (example for the measurement number 1):

```
Time     Measurement   Duration 
04:00    1             1
04:10    1             1
04:20    1             2
04:20    1             2
04:20    1             2
```

Longest duration

```
Time  Measurement Duration 
04:20 1           2
```

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14), `04:00` = c(1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11), `04:10` = c(1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11), `04:20` = c(1, 11, 1, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
1, 1, 11, 11, 11), `04:30` = c(1, 11, 1, 1, 3, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
1, 1, 13, 11, 11), `04:40` = c(1, 11, 1, 1, 3, 12, 11, 11, 4, 
1, 1, 13, 4, 11), `04:50` = c(4, 11, 11, 11, 3, 12, 11, 11, 4, 
11, 11, 13, 4, 11), `05:00` = c(4, 11, 11, 11, 3, 12, 11, 11, 
4, 13, 11, 13, 4, 11), `05:10` = c(4, 11, 11, 11, 3, 12, 11, 
11, 4, 13, 11, 13, 4, 11), `05:20` = c(4, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 
4, 11, 4, 13, 11, 13, 4, 11), `05:30` = c(4, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
13, 4, 13, 4, 13, 11, 1, 4, 13), `05:40` = c(4, 11, 3, 11, 11, 
13, 4, 13, 11, 13, 11, 1, 1, 13), `05:50` = c(11, 11, 3, 11, 
11, 13, 4, 13, 11, 13, 11, 1, 11, 13), `06:00` = c(11, 1, 3, 
11, 11, 13, 4, 13, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13), `06:10` = c(11, 1, 
3, 11, 11, 13, 4, 13, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13), `06:20` = c(11, 
1, 3, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'multiple starting times'?

Comment: This is quite unclear as to what the expected output should look like. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Maël thank you the outlook should contain the duration of the measurement per time-step and to select for each measurement the longest duration per time step. For example 04:00 will show the duration for each measurement (from 1-27) and it will select at 04:00 the longest duration per measurement

Comment: how do you compute the duration? and what do you mean by the 'longest duration per measurement'? do you mean across all time points? What does 11 stands for? Can you explain how you compute your expected output `Time 4:20 Measurement 1 Duration 2?`

Comment: @Maël thanks a.) duration calculation each time when a duration occurs is marked with one. For example at 04:00 measurement 11 occurs 13 times so the duration will 13 minutes. b.) the longest duration - for example at 06:20 measurement 11 has 2 different durations 1 and 4. So the longest duration of the measurement 11 at 06: 20 is 4; c.) not accros all the time point - instead per time step (per column); d.) 11 , 1, 13, etc.stands for a specific measurement e.) at 04:20 Mesurement 1 has 3 different 1 (id 1); 2(id 3+id 4) and 2 (id 10 + id 11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function, mainly using `rle`, that will get you the desired output for a specific measurement:

```r
f <- function(n){
  l <- lapply(df[-1], \(x) with(rle(x), lengths[values == n]))
  enframe(l, name = "Time", value = "Duration") %>% 
    unnest("Duration") %>% 
    mutate(Measurement = n, .before = "Duration")
}
```

output

```r
> f(1)
# A tibble: 20 × 3
   Time  Measurement Duration
   <chr>       <dbl>    <int>
 1 04:00           1        1
 2 04:10           1        1
 3 04:20           1        1
 4 04:20           1        2
 5 04:20           1        2
 6 04:30           1        1
 7 04:30           1        2
 8 04:30           1        2
 9 04:40           1        1
10 04:40           1        2
11 04:40           1        2
12 05:30           1        1
13 05:40           1        2
14 05:50           1        1
15 06:00           1        1
16 06:00           1        1
17 06:10           1        1
18 06:10           1        1
19 06:20           1        1
20 06:20           1        1
```

Get the maximum with `slice_max`:

```r
f(1) %>% 
  slice_max(Duration, n = 1, with_ties = F)

# A tibble: 1 × 3
  Time  Measurement Duration
  <chr>       <dbl>    <int>
1 04:20           1        2
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "timepoint", values_to = "Measurement") %>%
  arrange(id, Measurement) %>%
  type_convert() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  # Duration to first time point for each id
  mutate(Duration = timepoint - min(timepoint)) %>%
  # get the longest duration
  filter(Duration == max(Duration))
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   timepoint = col_time(format = "")
#> )
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [14]
#>       id timepoint Measurement Duration 
#>    <dbl> <time>          <dbl> <drtn>   
#>  1     1 06:20              11 8400 secs
#>  2     2 06:20               1 8400 secs
#>  3     3 06:20               3 8400 secs
#>  4     4 06:20              11 8400 secs
#>  5     5 06:20              11 8400 secs
#>  6     6 06:20              11 8400 secs
#>  7     7 06:20              11 8400 secs
#>  8     8 06:20              13 8400 secs
#>  9     9 06:20               1 8400 secs
#> 10    10 06:20              11 8400 secs
#> 11    11 06:20              11 8400 secs
#> 12    12 06:20              11 8400 secs
#> 13    13 06:20              11 8400 secs
#> 14    14 06:20              13 8400 secs
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>